# Strange toggle() behaviour on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery

People can add items to the database. I give them the option to add it at this very moment, or to manual select a date.

Therefor I got this HTML structure. (Note that I compromised the date and time picker to only a line of text)

```
<form action="..." method="post" class="feed">
    <div class="datetime">
        Select on what date to add:<br />
        <input type="radio" name="dateType" id="dtNow" value="now" checked />
        <label for="dtNow">Now</label><br />

        <input type="radio" name="dateType" id="dtSel" value="pickadate" />
        <label for="dtSel">Or pick a date:</label><br />
        <div>
            Date and time selector
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The next jQuery code comes with it:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datetime div').hide();

    $('.datetime [type=radio]').on('change', function() {
        $('.datetime div').toggle( $('.datetime [type=radio]:checked').val() == 'pickadate');

    });
});
```

It hides the div inside `.datetime` on page load. Then when the radio buttons are changed it shows or hides the div.

This works fine on desktop, but on mobile (HTC One M8s, with default browser) it doesn't. It shows the extra div, but won't hide it again.

When I add `$('body').append(' ');` before the `toggle()` line it does work.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhtfjy58/).

Comment: Does ($('.datetime [type=radio]:checked').val() == 'pickadate') output the same on mobile as browser (true/false)?

Comment: @DonBoots Well, that remarkable, it doesn't. When appending the value to the body, on desktop I get: `pickadate now pickadate now` on mobile I get `pickadate pickadate now pickadate now`. How is that possible? The function only fires on change, so how comes the value doesnt change with it instantly?

Comment: Not sure if that's the case, but I'd try without the self-closing `<input>` elements (no slash in the end), and also set a value to the `checked` property (`checked="true"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of struggling I have found a solution.

The problem seems to be that `$('.datetime [type=radio]:checked').val()` does not give the value at the time of changing it.

Changing it to `$('.datetime').find('[type=radio]:checked').val()` made it work.

Imo, both codes *should* give the same result, it however is unclear to me why it doesn't.

For a complete answer, this is the whole function:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datetime div').hide();

    $('.datetime [type=radio]').on('change', function() {
        $('.datetime div').toggle( $('.datetime').find('[type=radio]:checked').val() == 'pickadate');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the order of logic? Perhaps there is something fishy with the chaining of jQuery syntax or the default mobile browser just can't hang with the jQuery you're throwing at it without the append hack.

```
$(function() {
  $('.datetime div').hide();

  $('.datetime [type=radio]').on('change', function(e) {
    t = ($(this).val() == 'pickadate') ? true : false;
    $('.datetime div').toggle(t);
  });
});
```

This should do the same thing as

```
$(function() {
  $('.datetime div').hide();

  $('.datetime [type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $('.datetime div').toggle( $('.datetime [type=radio]:checked').val() == 'pickadate');

  });
});
```

just without whatever hangup the default mobile browser is stuck on.

You could also change your logic up to something like this if the browser is still not playing nicely.

```
$(function() {
  $('.datetime div').hide();

  $('.datetime [type=radio]').on('change', function(e) {
    toggleElement($(this).val());
  });
});

function toggleElement(el) {
  switch(el) {
    case 'pickadate':
        $('.datetime div').toggle(true);
        break;
    default:
        $('.datetime div').toggle(false);
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your afford @DonBoots! It helped me looking for workarounds, and finding a solution. +1